# Is my webView taking too much memory?

Tags: swift, memory, uiwebview

I have simple example where one `webView` is there which loads one link when the app loads successfully the Debug navigator looks like:

[image]

App takes 73.5 MB of Memory after that when I scroll down into simulator continuously memory increase too much like :

[image]

can anybody explain me why it is taking too much memory?
Or tell me if it causes any problem?

here is my code for this:

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

   }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this

Comment: you can use WKWebView instead of UIWebView which will not take more memory

Answer (score 0):

you can use WKWebView instead of UIWebView which will not take more memory, here is an example how to use it in **swift 3**:

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController 

{

        var webView: WKWebView!

        override func viewDidload() {
        super.viewDidload()

        let url = "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456"
        let requestURL = URL(string:url)
        let request =  URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.load(request)
}
}
```